# So, im doing the updation in my django project and i'm getting a error for reverse match

Tags: python, django, python-3.x

THE ERROR IS--

```
NoReverseMatch at /updatemedicine/2

Reverse for 'updatemedicine' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['updatemedicine/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/updatemedicine/2
Django Version:     2.2.4
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'updatemedicine' with keyword arguments '{'pk1': ''}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['updatemedicine/(?P<pk1>[0-9]+)$']

Exception Location:     C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 668
Python Executable:  C:\Users\lenovo\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\python.exe
Python Version:     3.7.4
Python Path:    

['D:\\django project\\admin4',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\python37.zip',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\win32\\lib',
 'C:\\Users\\lenovo\\AppData\\Local\\Programs\\Python\\Python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\Pythonwin']
```

MY HTML CODE IS ===

```
{% extends 'Pharmacetical/homepage.html' %}
{% block content %}


<div class="box box-warning">
            <div class="box-header with-border">
              <h3 class="box-title">Add Medicines Here</h3>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-header -->
            <div class="box-body">
              <form role="form" method="POST" action="{% url 'updatemedicine' pk1=med.pk1 %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                <!-- text input -->
                  {% csrf_token %}
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Disease Name</label>
                  <select class="form-control" name="desigid">
                  {% for i in d %}
                  <option value="{{ med.dsg_id }}">{{ i.diseas }}</option>
                  {% endfor %}
               </select>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Medicine Name</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="medname" id="" value="{{ med.medicine }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Uses</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="uses" id="" value="{{ med.uses }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Side Effects</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="effects" id="" value="{{ med.sideeffects }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Precautions</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="precaution" id=""  value="{{ med.precautions }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Overdoses</label>
                  <textarea class="form-control" rows="3" name="over" id="" value="{{ med.overdoses }}" placeholder="Enter ..."></textarea>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                  <label>Image</label>
                  <input type="file" name="pho" value="{{ med.images }}" >
                </div>

                <!-- textarea -->

                <button type="submit" value="Addme" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>



              </form>
            </div>
            <!-- /.box-body -->
          </div>
{% endblock %}
```

MY URL IS===

```
path("updatemedicine/<int:pk1>",views.updatemedicine,name="updatemedicine"),
```

MY VIEW CODE IS====

```
def updatemedicine(request,pk1):
    if request.method == "POST":
        medi = request.POST['medname']
        use = request.POST['uses']
        side = request.POST['effects']
        precaut = request.POST['precaution']
        over = request.POST['over']

        s = Medicines.objects.get(id=pk1)
        s.dsg = Diseases.objects.get(id=request.POST['desigid'])
        s.medicine = medi`enter code here`
        s.uses = use
        s.sideeffects = side
        s.precautions = precaut`enter code here`
        s.overdoses = over
        s.images = request.FILES['pho']
        s.save()

        return redirect("/datatablee")
    else:
        d = Diseases.objects.all()
        med = Medicines.objects.get(id=pk1)
        return render(request,'Pharmacetical/editmedicine.html',{"d":d,"med":med})
```

AND MY MODELS CODE IS===

```
class Medicines(models.Model):
    dsg = models.ForeignKey(Diseases,on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medicine = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uses = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    sideeffects = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    precautions = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    overdoses = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    images = models.ImageField(upload_to='medicines/')
```

So the thing is i checked my data base the data insdide the table is same and belongs to same id but everytime try to update it gives me an error and i dont know how to resolve it. please help me out on this one and it would be appreciate it

Answer (score 2):

In your template you are using `pk1=med.pk1` but your model `Medicines` doesn't have a field called `pk1`.

In order to get the `primary_key` of your model, use `.pk`, e.g. `pk1=med.pk`.

Comment: ok thank you its working but i had another problem which is when i click on update button the data in the input tag showing but the other data's in the text area tag is not showing and for refrence please check my html code and thank you once again for resolving the error and helping me and also in the image tag

Comment: @GaganSharma Glad it helped, and please consider marking the answer as accepted. Furthermore: If you are having a different problem now, I'd recommend you to create another question for that.